# A stick of random length is broken in two. Given the length of one piece, what is the expected length of the stick?

Tags: probability, self-study, conditional-expectation

A stick has unknown length $l\sim U(a,b)$, with $a,b$ known. It is broken in two with uniform probablity, and we are told the length of a randomly chosen piece. What is the expected length of the other piece/the whole stick? What if we know that the chosen piece was the longer/shorter one? Bonus: multiple pieces.

*Note*: I have looked up other questions, but all those I could find related to the expected lengths of pieces of a stick of fixed length.

*Update*: I think I found an answer to the first question:

Let $l\sim U(a,b)$, $M\sim U(a,l)$. So $M$ is the length of the first piece (if we choose them randomly, it shouldn't matter which one we know). The pdf of $l|M=m$ should then be $1/(b-m)$ on $[m,b]$ and $0$ elsewhere (ie uniform), and we have

$\mathbb{E}(l|M=m) = \int_m^b \frac{x}{b-m} \text{d}x = \frac{b^2-m^2}{2(b-m)} = \frac{b+m}{2}$

This makes sense intuitively. I was initially fixated on using MLE, which gives a less intuitive answer. With this pdf the MLE should be $b=m$, which makes a lot less sense intuitively.

Comment: What have you tried? Where are you stuck? If this is part of a class, what are the topics that you've covered which you think might pertain to this problem, and how would you apply that knowledge?

Comment: Have you tried to write this question as a Bayesian problem?

Comment: It's a problem that came up in a discussion with a friend, not related to a course (I think it was a brainteaser somewhere). I was fixated on using MLE which seems to give an unintuitive answer. I tried it again with conditional expectations and I found a solution for the basic question, added.